# Error when using FindRoot

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Currently I have an equation with boundary conditions as such, $A \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}= C_{F}F, \psi(\frac{1}{2})=0,\psi\:'(0)=0$ and I have to use a "shooting method" to find the Dirichlet boundary condition at $x=0$, shown below:

```
F = 96485.3321;
A = 5.312*10^-24;
CF = 1000;
fun[y_?NumericQ] := Module[{eqns, sol, ics, x, psi},
  eqns = {A*D[psi[x], x, x] == CF*F};
  ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[x] == 0 /. x -> 0};
  sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, {psi[x]}, {x, 0, 1/2}][[1]];
  psi[x] /. sol /. x -> 1/2]
ic = FindRoot[fun[x], {x, 0}]
```

but the FindRoot function gives an error:

```
FindRoot:Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x} = {0.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
```

Can anyone suggest a way to get around this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At first we directly solve the equation by `DSolve` and `Solve`.

```
F = 96485.3321;
A = 5.312*10^-24;
CF = 1000;
eqns = {A*psi''[x] == CF*F};
ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[0] == 0};
sol1 = DSolve[{eqns, ics}, psi, x][[1]];
sol2 = Solve[psi[1/2] == 0 /. sol1[[1]], y][[1]]
sol = sol1 /. sol2
```

[image]

```
{eqns, psi[1/2] == 0, psi'[0] == 0} /. sol
```

> `{{True}, True, True}`.

- Then we using shooting method to solve it again.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
F = 96485.3321;
A = 5.312*10^-24;
CF = 1000;
fun[y_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{eqns, sol, ics, x, psi}, eqns = {A*psi''[x] == CF*F};
  ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[0] == 0};
  sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, {psi}, {x, 0, 1/2}][[1]];
  psi /. sol]
Plot[fun[y][1/2], {y, -10*10^30, 0}]
FindRoot[fun[y][1/2], {y, -2*10^30}]
```

[image]

[image]

- The same as `ParametricNDSolve`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
F = 96485.3321;
A = 5.312*10^-24;
CF = 1000;
eqns = {A*psi''[x] == CF*F};
ics = {psi[0] == y, psi'[0] == 0};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqns, ics}, {psi}, {x, 0, 1/2}, {y}]
Plot[psi[y][1/2] /. sol, {y, -10*10^30, 0}]
FindRoot[psi[y][1/2] /. sol, {y, -2*10^30}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would you mind explaining why in `Plot[fun[y][1/2], {y, -10*10^30, 0}]` and the subsequent `FindRoot` function,  [1/2] is needed after fun[y]? @cvgmt

Comment: In my code, the `fun[y]` is a pure function` with parametric `y`. We need to find the parametric `y` when it satisfies the equation `psi[1/2]==0`,  that is  `fun[y][1/2]==0`, here `psi` is `fun[y]`.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thanks a lot!